# Fetch tweets with a specific hashtag using Scribe

Tags: java, twitter, hashtag, scribe, twitter-streaming-api

Can I use scribe to fetch tweets with a specific hashtag using streeming api? I work in java and I want use scribe in an appengine project. Is it possible? I try the following code:

```
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                            .apiKey(MYCONSUMERKEY)
                            .apiSecret(MYCONSUMERSECRET)         
                            .debug()                       
                            .build();

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
    request.addBodyParameter("track", "prova");
    Token requestToken = new Token(MYACCESSTOKEN,MYACCESSTOKENSECRET);

    service.signRequest(requestToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
```

The response is:

```
    signing request: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json
  setting token to: Token[MYACCESSTOKEN,MYACCESSTOKENSECRET]
  generating signature...
  base string is: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fstream.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Ffilter.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DMYCONSUMERKEY%26oauth_nonce%3Dxxx%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3Dxxx%26oauth_token%3Dxxx%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26track%3Dprova
  signature is: 5UU55rZqzjiaRwSNGz/jrcffPoM=
  appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> xxx , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> xxx , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> MYCONSUMERKEY , oauth_token -> xxx , oauth_timestamp -> xxx }
  using Http Header signature

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
```

Comment: that `debug()` call makes scribe print some stuff in the console, can you paste that here please?

Answer (score 1):

as i see from your code you are trying to sign your GET call with requestToken, you have to take first an accessToken, then use this accessToken to sign any GET/POST calls. Try doing like this:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                        .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                        .apiKey(MYCONSUMERKEY)
                        .apiSecret(MYCONSUMERSECRET)         
                        .debug()                       
                        .build();

//get a request token
Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

//go to this url
System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));

//after autorizing your twitter account you will see a blank page, in the url you will see 
//a parameter called oauth_verifier=XXXXXXXXXXX;
//paste the xxxx after this code: 

Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());

//now request an accessToken to service: 
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

//once you have accessToken, you should use it to do GET/POST calls:
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
//GET CALL DO NOT ACCEPT PARAMETER
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
System.out.println(response.getBody());


//POST CALL
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
request.addBodyParameter("track", "prova");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```